# Usuario creado por ldap no puede iniciar sección

Tags: php, windows-server, ldap

Cree un usuario por medio de esta sintaxis en php, se crea y todo, pero no puede iniciar sección el usuario, marca credenciales invalidas cada que se intenta. Alguien me puede ayudar, o se debe habilitar alguna parte en el servidor el acceso a los usuarios por ldap.
Se esta usando un windows server con active directory, y el protocolo ldap.

```
$ds = '192.168.1.10'; 
$portldap = 389; 
$ldap_username = 'CN=Administrador,CN=Users,DC=Local,DC=com';
$ldap_password = 'rootadm1';
$ldap_password_user = $ldap_password;

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect($ds, $portldap);
if($ldap_connection ){
    // We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
    ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
    ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

    $r = ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password);
    if($r === TRUE){
        $CN = htmlspecialchars($_POST["cn"]);
        $ldaprecord['cn'] =  $CN;
        $ldaprecord['sAMAccountName'] = $_POST["sAMAccountName"]; //20caract
        $ldaprecord['userPrincipalName'] = $_POST["userprincipalname"];
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][0] = "top";
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][1] = "person";
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][2] = "organizationalPerson";
        $ldaprecord["objectClass"][3] = "user";
        $ldaprecord['description']= $_POST["description"]; 
        $ldaprecord["userAccountControl"][0] = "66656"; 
        
        $ldap_new = 'CN='.$CN.',CN=Users,DC=Local,DC=com';

        $result = ldap_add($ldap_connection, $ldap_new, $ldaprecord);        
        if($result) {  
            //Success creating user - Add password
            $addPrecord['userPassword'] = '{MD5}' . base64_encode(pack('H*',md5($ldap_password_user)));
            //$addPrecord["unicodePwd"][0] = iconv( 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $ldap_password_user );
            $add_record=  ldap_modify($ldap_connection, $ldap_new, $addPrecord);
            if($add_record){
                ldap_close($ldap_connection);
                return $result;
            }
            else {
                echo "LDAP Error: ".ldap_error($ldap_connection)."\n";
                exit;
            }
        }
        else {
                echo "LDAP Error: ".ldap_error($ldap_connection)."\n";
                exit;
        }
    }
}
else {
     echo "cannot connect to LDAP server at $ds.";
}
```

Comment: tiene tu maquina permitido el acceso a ese servidor?

Comment: Si tiene acceso, ya he hecho pruebas deshabilitado el firewall, probando a nivel de telnet pero ni asi se conecta. Tienes algún consejo para ayudarme.